# AWS CLI not automatically using multipart upload for s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, multipart

According to AWS pages, if a file size is big enough it will automatically use multi part uploads so I can run this command

```
aws s3 cp large_test_file s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/
```

and the upload should be multipart.

However, I am uploading a 1gb file and it seems to be uploading it as a normal file.

Furthermore, my bucket policy has no permissions for multipart list or upload (just put object) so I don't understand how that is working.

Would like some clarity on this if it is

- Indeed using multipart upload (without informing me)
- How is it able to do so without me granting it permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for Multipart Uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html) mentions this near the section on permissions:

> Create Multipart Upload
>
> You must be allowed to perform the `s3:PutObject` action on an object to create multipart upload.
>
> The bucket owner can allow other principals to perform the `s3:PutObject` action.

In other words, the `PutObject` permission allows `PutObject`, but also `CreateMultipartUpload` and related calls necessary to perform a multipart upload.